# Hide maven output apart from the tree using mvn dependency:tree in batch file

Tags: file, maven, batch-file, dependencies

I have written a batch wrapper script which runs

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

on a load of maven projects.

I want the output to display only the trees, I don't need all the other things maven prints out e.g.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects
```

I have tried **quiet mode** but because the tree is not an error I see no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [outputFile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#outputFile) property to have it output it to a file. Also look at [appendOutput](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#appendOutput) if you need to append the output all together into one file.

Comment: Thank you, does this completely remove all other maven output?

Comment: The output file will contain just the dependency tree.

Comment: Thanks again, although it does not appear to be be writing to the file. "mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes:mydep" finds a small tree but adding the "-DoutputFile=tree" simply makes an empty file called "tree". Any ideas?

Comment: Doing just "mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=tree" does create the tree just fine in the file. You might want to check your pom or any parent poms you have to see if you have configured the dependency plugin that might interfere with this.

Comment: After checking there is no configuration of the dependency plugin. If I remove the -Dincludes=mydep it simply prints the name of the parent pom to the file, but no tree. I'm using mvn 2.2.1 any other suggestions?

Comment: Try with Maven 3 and the latest dependency plugin?

Comment: For those of you who had a similar problem to myself, using the extension .out seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep to filter out unwanted elements:

```
function mvndeps {
    mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes="$1" | grep '^[^\[]\|ERROR\|\] B\|\]net\|\][[:space:]]*\\';
}
```